# Return the XML source for the node with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Please imagine XML node in variable `n`.

If I access this node through MSXML, I can get node's XML source with `.xml` property, i.e. `n.xml` will return whole node source.

How can I do the same with lxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.tostring()` method](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring):

```
from lxml import etree

print etree.tostring(node)
```